# What would be the law with regards to the Sukka in Manhattan?

Tags: halacha, chabad, sukkah

A few members of a community board in Manhattan [do not want to give permission](http://www.vosizneias.com/92121/2011/09/26/manhattan-ny-some-board-members-say-law-prohibits-construction-of-sukkah) for a Sukka in a park (because of 1st amendment issues).

According to the [Shulchan Aruch Harav](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16088&pgnum=398), one cannot make a blessing in a stolen Sukkah. So if the board would end up forbidding the Sukka (and win on appeal), yet someone were to put one up, would one be able to make a blessing in that Sukka?

What if the shul wouldn't have asked, and the police wouldn't have noticed, then would the Sukkah still stay kosher?

---

Relevent question: [Sukkah in the Soviet Union](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9838/sukkah-in-the-soviet-union)

Answer (score 2):

A sukkah gezulah means the sukkah itself is stolen, not the land that its on. If someone holds even using land without permission is gezulah so then it would be a problem here too. Either way, its probably a chilul haShem to go build something in public without permission.

Comment: Look in Syif 11 where the Shulchan Aruch Harav says that one cannot lchatchila build a sukka in public domain (and even bdieved one cannot say a bracha on such a sukka) because the ground is stolen from the public.