# Succah on public property and Mitzvah by Averah

Tags: halacha, sukkah

1. What are the Halachic implications of a Succah built on a public property? Is it called a Succah Gezulah or the land can't be stolen, etc.?
2. Similarly, if the Succah poses serious inconveniences to the public (like a Succah on a sidewalk cases people to step down on the road, or the Succa's protruding poles hurt people), can it be called Mitzvah by Everah and invalidate the Succah? To what extent?

Comment: This was discussed in the beginning of http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/92218-contemporary-sukkos-shailos-everyone-needs-to-know/

Comment: Very similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9838/sukkah-in-the-soviet-union Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/what-would-be-the-law-with-regards-to-the-sukka-in-manhattan

Comment: Unfortunately Both address only the Lubavitchers. My question is general and addresses the mainstream (ShuA MB etc)