# Are adjoining Sukkoth ok?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, architecture-design

Is there any reason* neighbors could not build adjoining Sukkoth?

What I mean is, suppose there were four** row houses, which shared an open patio/courtyard with four** row houses behind them, and this open courtyard could be divided into about a 12x15'** section for each home.  Could these neighbors pool their resources together to build adjoining Sukkoth, each sharing a wall (and perhaps even a door) with at least two neighbors?

<sub>*I mean any Halachic reason; let's assume all the neighbors are great friends.</sub>

<sub>**I picked a random number.</sub>

(Illustration interpreted from question text)

[image: Illustration]

Comment: So you're asking if the individual sukkot are valid even if the whole is not valid as a single sukkah?  (If the whole is valid, then seemingly internal divisions wouldn't matter.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think an answer could address whether the whole thing is valid as one sukkah, valid as 8 sukkot, or invalid. Perhaps there is no distinction between "valid as (one/four)"

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9838/sukkah-in-the-soviet-union

Comment: @AL, that works. (Also, it was just an example. It could be about any adjoining Sukkoth.)

Comment: @SethJ Not like I looked this case up anywhere, but I can't imagine why they would be invalid just because they're touching. For example, a sukkah can use a house as a third wall with no concern, why should this be different. Is there another aspect to the question that you're concerned about?

Comment: @Al I can't either, necessarily; but I'm just wondering if one person's Sukkah wall can be used for else's Mitzvah.