# Benefit from Court Awarded Real Estate

Tags: civil-procedure

Regarding real estate that is awarded to a Jew in a non-halachic court, at the initiation of the awardee, by use of the discretionary powers of a judge, on a basis that has no concordance with Jewish law.  Is it permissible, or problematic, to live in that property at the invitation of the property owner?  Is it permissible or problematic to rent living space there?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a look at our [tour] for some helpful information about the site. Looking forward to learning with you!

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9963/

Comment: Thanks DonielF.  I read the related post. The question would be if levying taxes is the same as a discretionary decision by  judge.  If yes, perhaps there is nothing wrong with a plaintiff availing oneself of that opportunity lechatchila?