# Legal minyan in Stamford Hill

Tags: product-recommendation, synagogue, geography, minyan, dina-dmalchusa-dina

As of October 2020 the UK government has established [strict laws](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-outbreak-faqs-what-you-can-and-cant-do/coronavirus-outbreak-faqs-what-you-can-and-cant-do) and [very specific guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/covid-19-guidance-for-the-safe-use-of-places-of-worship-during-the-pandemic-from-4-july/high-holy-day-services-and-gatherings-covid-19-checklist#sukkot-and-shemini-atzeretsimchat-torah) for the currently ongoing holiday.

[It would seem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9817/3073) that we have to keep these regulations, especially since they have been made to keep everyone safe, and because they actually [are enforced](https://www.met.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/c19/coronavirus-covid-19/coronavirus-covid-19-police-powers/) (a local Judaica store clerk told me that police had stopped by and fined their customers):

> - £200 for the first offence, lowered to £100 if paid within 14 days
> - £400 for the second offence, then doubling for each further offence up to a maximum of £6,400

Is there any minyan in (preferably north-western) Stamford Hill (north-east London, England; N15/N16/E5) that abides by current COVID-19 laws?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to daven at the Golders Green United Synagogue which is under the auspices of the Chief Rabbi of the United Synagogue.

If you are going to attend then you will have to contact them to find out what their criteria is I.e. whether it’s for members only also you will have to register your contact details for track and trace.

I don’t know if the federation of synagogues have a Shul in NW London but you can google.

I hope this helps

Stay safe!

EDIT:

There’s South Tottenham 020 8880 2731 the post code is N15 6UR. Call to find out if they are open. It’s United Synagogue.

Comment: I've now clarified that I'm asking about north-western *Stamford Hill*, which itself is in north-*east* London. Golders Green is in north-*west* London.

Comment: There’s South Tottenham 020 8880 2731 the post code is N15 6UR. Call to find out if they are open. It’s United Synagogue.  Please don’t be offended but from what I heard from people that Chassidishe Shul’s don’t observe social distancing or have proper COVID -19 guidance in place. That’s why I can only suggest United Synagogue at the moment. I will be happy to accept the opposite if people have attend such Shul’s(Chassidishe).

Comment: I'm not at all offended. Rather, my question is based on my own observations that match what you've heard.

Comment: Why the down vote? Does it not answer or not even a possible answer?

Comment: @DanielRoss perhaps someone doesn't like Golders Green or the United Synagogue...

Comment: @DanielRoss Wasn't from me, but your post doesn't really answer the question. You should amend it with the content of your comment about South Tottenham.